# Simple Powershell command hangs Visual Studio 2010 in post-build event

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, build

I have a one line Powershell command that works perfectly well from the command line.

When I add it into my VS2010 project's post-build commands however, it goes to run, but then just hangs Visual Studio. It is almost as if Visual Studio is just sitting there waiting for the Powershell command to complete, i.e. the command line just needs to press enter to close the window or something.. Because CPU usage is dead low.

Do I have to do anything special to get a normal Powershell command to run happily from within the VS2010 post-build window?

The command is:

```
[io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\test.js', ((gc C:\test.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' -join "`r`n"))
```

So within VS, I add the prefix to launch it via Powershell, like so:

```
Powershell [io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\test.js', ((gc C:\test.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' -join "`r`n"))
```

**Update**

This ended up doing the trick. Thanks for everyone's great input.

```
Powershell -command "[io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\test.js', ((gc C:\.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' -join \"`r`n\"))"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post build steps are run by `cmd.exe`, so you need to ensure everything is escaped to be processed by PowerShell *and not `cmd.exe`*.

In your command, `cmd.exe` will try and perform the pipe and `sc` itself. A quick test with a text file passed to `sc.exe` (command line service control utility) indicates it shows help and waits for keyboard input when passed an invalid command line.

I suggest use of full cmdlet names as well to help avoid ambiguity.

The command should be something like (test in an interactive `cmd.exe` to confirm):

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -command "(get-content C:\www\js\test.min.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' | set-content C:\www\js\test.min.js"
```

"

Comment: Thanks for your help. What if my 'command' actually has a double quote inside it already?

Comment: @Aaron: `cmd` does have an escape characters (`^` IIRC), or maybe if you double up the quotes (`""`)? Cmd's documentation is painful to find so you might need some effort. Another options would be to put the PSH script into a file (add to the project as "no build") and use the command line to execute that.

Comment: Ok this is it. This fully works perfectly. I was also able to chain 4 commands together using semicolons so that I could call them all from a single line from within VS. Thanks again:

Powershell -command "[io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\test.js', ((gc C:\.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' -join \"`r`n\"));[io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\test.js', ((gc C:\test.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' -join \"`r`n\"));[io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\test.js', ((gc C:\test.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' -join \"`r`n\"));[io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\test.js', ((gc C:\test.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' -join \"`r`n\"))"

Comment: Consider using script file. The it is much easier to run it and you have no problems with escape characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gc C:\www\js\test.min.js -read 0
```

Or first store result from `gc` to a local variable and then call `sc`. There is open read handle that prevents PowerShell from opening the file for writing.

Comment: That completed successfully and VS didn't hang.. Hey its you again who helped me in the other thread. Thanks so much! So now I just want to get VS to run your great command that you showed me in the other thread.. Anything I can do to get around the open read handle? This is happening in post-build, so I thought I would be finished with all the files. The command is: [io.file]::WriteAllText('C:\test.js', ((gc C:\test.js) -replace 'HELLO','GOODBYE' -join "`r`n"))

Comment: I think the command `[io.file]::WriteAllText(path, (gc path))` should run with no problem, because the content of the file is first read and then writtern with `WriteAllText`.

Comment: It was still having some weird issues, but I think your original hunch was correct in that they were probably file locking issues. VS/Powershell combined does seem quite flaky. In the end, it seemed to work no problems with the final snippet I posted above. Thx again heaps.